# When an instance method calls a class method, I have to use self.class_method?

Tags: ruby

I'm getting an error so I guess I have to reference a class method from inside of an instance method with self.class_method_name, but why is that?

Shouldn't it resolve this by itself? Confused.

```
def self.blah(string)
  ..
end

def some_method()
  some_thing = blah("hello")
end
```

Comment: The code above, if put into IRB, would work. Put something like `class Foo ... end` around it next time.

Comment: Its a module, not a class, does that change things?

Comment: Yes, because `self.class.blah` probably wouldn't work. If you don't provide a proper code example, you won't be able to get a suitable answer.

Comment: I figured it out, just did:  Module_Name::Staticmethod

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
# This won't work
class Foo
  def self.blah(string)
    puts "self.blah called with a string of #{string}"
  end

  def some_method
    # This won't work
    self.blah("hello")
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.some_method
```

It won't work, because it'll look for the instance method `Foo#blah`. Instead, you're looking for `Foo.bar`.

To make `some_method` call `Foo.bar`, you have to make `some_method` refer to the `Foo` class, and then call `blah` on it.

```
class Foo
  def self.blah(string)
    puts "self.blah called with a string of #{string}"
  end

  def some_method
    # This will work
    self.class.blah("hello")
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.some_method
```

The reason you have `def self.blah` to define the method, but `self.class.blah` to call the method, is that in the former, `self` refers to the `Foo` class, while in the latter, `self` refers to the `foo` object, so you need `self.class` to refer to the `Foo` class.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to think of `self` as part of the method name, that way it's clear that you never defined a `blah` method, you defined only a `self.blah` method. *(To clarify: the previous sentence shouldn't be thought of too much, so please don't read into it, as it's not how things are actually working, just a sort of "layman's terms" attempt at describing why it doesn't work.)*

Also, what if you *had* defined a `blah` instance method in addition to the class method? If calling `blah` was enough to access the class method, how would you call the instance method?

Finally, there really isn't any such thing as a class method in Ruby, "class methods" are really methods of the singleton class.

Comment: i see, I'm going to read up on that singleton method notion... :)

Comment: With regards to the first paragraph, you can't talk about `self.blah` without knowing what `self` refers to.

Comment: I'm actually using a module, so would it just be self.module_name.bar?

Comment: @Blankman: Can you edit your question to clarify what you're asking?

Comment: my methods are not in a class, they are in a module i.e. module MY_MODULE_NAME def self.blah .. end end